# Scanning "$" sign in C

Tags: c, string, fgets

I have this code that extracts words from a string (sentence) using a function I've written, but I'm having trouble when a `$` sign is at the beginning of a word! However, it works when the `$` sign is in the word (between other letters) or at the end of a letter.

> $25 : Error
>   $ : Error
>   25$ : Works fine

My code works fine for every other character or setting so I'm sure it's not a logical problem with my code.

This is how I'm scanning the string:

```
fgets(string, 256, stdin);
```

and I store characters before space one by one like this:

```
word[i] = string[i];
```

The error I get in VS is this:

> Debug Assertion failed
>   file location: ctype.c
>   Expression `c>=-1 && c<=255`

and I am using the `ctype.h` library.

Comment: We need to see your entire program.  Please read and follow the instructions at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: Are you sure it is a regula `$`, not some weird unicode symbol?

Comment: The `isxxxxx()` functions defined in ctype.h only accept values from -1 to 255 (inclusive).  The error is telling you that you passed them a value outside of that range.  For example `isalpha(12345)`.  You need to check the value(s) you are passing to these functions.

Comment: Thanks John that was my mistake, I replaced it with my own function and it works now.

Comment: *I'm sure its not a logical problem* is an assumption which you can not be sure about.